# SCNetworkReachability compiling error

Tags: iphone

I tried to compile Ercia Sadun's sample code [here](http://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C13-Networking/14-Web%20Browser/), but this error came up:

```
warning: in /Users/interdev/iphone source code/Web Browser/Classes/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration, missing required architecture i386 in file
    Undefined symbols:
      "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
          +[UIDevice(Reachability) scheduleReachabilityWatcher:] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
      "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
          +[UIDevice(Reachability) hostAvailable:] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
          +[UIDevice(Reachability) pingReachabilityInternal] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
      "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
          +[UIDevice(Reachability) unscheduleReachabilityWatcher] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
      "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
          +[UIDevice(Reachability) scheduleReachabilityWatcher:] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
          +[UIDevice(Reachability) scheduleReachabilityWatcher:] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
          +[UIDevice(Reachability) unscheduleReachabilityWatcher] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
      "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
          +[UIDevice(Reachability) hostAvailable:] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
          +[UIDevice(Reachability) pingReachabilityInternal] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
        "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
            +[UIDevice(Reachability) scheduleReachabilityWatcher:] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
        "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
            +[UIDevice(Reachability) hostAvailable:] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
            +[UIDevice(Reachability) pingReachabilityInternal] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
        "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
            +[UIDevice(Reachability) unscheduleReachabilityWatcher] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
        "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
            +[UIDevice(Reachability) scheduleReachabilityWatcher:] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
            +[UIDevice(Reachability) scheduleReachabilityWatcher:] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
            +[UIDevice(Reachability) unscheduleReachabilityWatcher] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
        "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
            +[UIDevice(Reachability) hostAvailable:] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
            +[UIDevice(Reachability) pingReachabilityInternal] in UIDevice-Reachability.o
      ld: symbol(s) not found
      collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    Build failed (5 errors)
```

...Even after I added systemConfiguration.framework, it reported the same error. Why did it do this, and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Which SystemConfiguration.framework did you add? The first line clearly stated

> warning: in `/Users/interdev/iphone source code/Web Browser/Classes/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration`, missing required architecture i386 in file

But you should add the SDK one, in `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks`.

The framework should be added by "Add Existing Framework..." in the right-click menu on the project.

Comment: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework

Comment: @user If you are compiling for simulator the path should be `/Dev/Pl/`**`iPhoneSimulator.platform`**`/Dev/SDKs/`**`iPhoneSimulator3.1.sdk`**`/Sys/Lib/Fr/SysConf.fr`. Select the SysConf framework, view Info, and select "relative to current SDK".

Comment: I try to add the framework you said, but when I check by clicking 'Getinfo'

it still points to 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework

I checked Erica Sadun's project, it works well now.

but if I add their source codes to my project, the error still exists.

Comment: @user: You need to select "relative to current SDK" for your project as well, not just Erica's.

Comment: I fixed it

Thanks a lot

KennyTM